# Jest is failed to running with Mock files with Error Message Your test suite must contain at least one test

Tags: jestjs

I have webpack and jest,I have my jest option setting as below:

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
      "^.+\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__tests__/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "^.+\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/__tests__/__mocks__/styleMock.js"
    }
  }
```

styleMock.js content:

```
export default '';
```

fileMock.js  content:

```
 export default 'test-file-stub';
```

Jest Fail to Run. with below error:

```
 FAIL  __tests__/__mocks__/fileMock.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Your test suite must contain at least one test.

 FAIL  __tests__/__mocks__/styleMock.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Your test suite must contain at least one test.
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just that Jest should not try to execute those files as tests. You should change the testMatch in jest.config.js to only check for `.spec.js` files or `.test.js` files :

```js
  testMatch: [
    "**/__tests__/**/*.[tj]s?(x)",
    "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[tj]s?(x)"
  ],
```